# Best Practice for Serializing CG Structs to Proper Objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, serialization, core-graphics

What is the best practice for storing CoreGraphics struct based values such as `CGRect`, `CGPoint`, etc into proper objects for the purpose of storing in collection classes?

You can either use `NSValue`:

```
    NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect];

    [values addObject:value];

    CGRect rectValue = [values[0] CGRectValue];
```

or `NSString`:

```
    NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    NSString *string = NSStringFromCGRect(rect);

    [values addObject:string];

    CGRect rectValue = CGRectFromString(string);
```

Just wondering if there was something I was missing and there was an advantage to one over the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way is more "canonical" because it has smaller footprint in memory, and does not require much CPU to do the conversion. There is also no possibility of the precision loss due to conversion to decimal and back: the floats inside the `struct`s are stored in their native format.

To be fair, the differences between the two approaches are negligible, unless you need to deal with tens of thousands of objects.

Comment: But tenths of thousands is only hundreds ;)  It's not funny after you fixed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are valid. The use of `NSValue` is most likely far more efficient than using the `NSString` approach. String processing is generally much slower than the simple memory copying used by `NSValue`.

If you are only doing a few it probably make no difference overall. But if you have lots of these to convert, go with the `NSValue` approach for better (faster) performance.